# Container CPU Usage is higher than Node CPU Usage

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter, cadvisor

### Background

I am trying to distribute the energy consumption of a whole system (e.g. `raspberrypi`) to pods of serverless functions. Unfortunately, I am receiving weird results. I already got the whole energy measurement setup and for a simple start, I have 1 Pod of a serverless function, lets name it `analyze-sentence`, deployed on `OpenFaaS` in Kubernetes.

I use Prometheus with `node-exporter` and `cadvisor` in order to get metrics indiciating the CPU Usage of my Kubernetes nodes and the CPU Usage of containers. For the energy consumption I have written my own custom exporter, that provides corresponding metrics.

### What I've tried

I thought to come up with a simple formula first that only takes CPU Usage into account.
It is composed of:

- Total CPU Usage of the System, given in **Percentage**.
  Afaik, I can use the metric `node_cpu_seconds_total` for this.
- Total Number of CPU Cores of the System.
  Afaik, I can use the metric `machine_cpu_cores` for this.
- CPU Usage of the Pod, given in **Number of Cores** used.
  Afaik, I can use the metric `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` for this. (There is only 1 container in the pod anyway)
- Measured Energy Consumption of the System, given in **Ampere-seconds (As)**.
  For this I use my own metric, `powerexporter_power_consumption_ampere_seconds_total`. Its a `counter`. It is safe to say that the values of the metric are correct, so I don't think the problems are related to this metric.

With this I can first compute the CPU Usage of the Pod relative to the total CPU Usage of the whole System, given in Percentage:

`(CPU Usage (Pod) / Number of Cores) / CPU Usage (System)`

which returns something in the interval `[0...1]` and then I could multiply the result with the measured energy consumption.

My idea was, when retrieving the metrics from Prometheus, to take the past 1 minute into account. For the CPU Usage its probably better to get an average using the `rate` function. So I want average CPU Usage of the System in the past minute, average CPU Usage of the Pod in the past minute, etc.

The values are computed using the following PromQL queries (let's assume to use `raspberrypi`) instance:

- CPU Usage (System)

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job='node-exporter', instance='raspberrypi', mode='idle'}[1m])) * 100) > 0
```

- Number of System CPU Cores

```
machine_cpu_cores{node='raspberrypi'}
```

- CPU Usage (Pod)

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container='analyze-sentence', image!='', container_name!='POD'}[1m]) > 0
```

- Energy Consumption (System)

```
idelta(powerexporter_power_consumption_ampere_seconds_total{instance='raspberrypi'}[2m:1m])
```

`idelta` takes the last two samples in a range query and computes the difference. So with this query I only get two samples anyway, the total energy consumption measured at the current minute and at the past minute. So this should give me the amount of energy consumed within the past 60 seconds.

### The Problem

I am receiving weird results regarding the CPU Usage. Sometimes, the CPU Usage of the Pod is higher than the CPU Usage of the System, which obviously doesn't make any sense. At first I thought the timestamp of the individual metrics aren't the same, but this is not the case. See a sample result after querying the Prometheus REST API for the needed data:

```py
2022-07-30 13:36:05,840 - __main__ - INFO >>> CPU Cores Query >>> [Timestamp: 1659180963.405 | Number of Cores: 8]
2022-07-30 13:36:05,938 - __main__ - INFO >>> Node CPU Usage Query >>> [Timestamp: 1659180963.503 | CPU Usage: 15.909242428069987 %]
2022-07-30 13:36:06,029 - __main__ - INFO >>> Container CPU Usage Query >>> [Timestamp: 1659180963.594 | CPU Usage: 1.4602082000000034 Cores
2022-07-30 13:36:06,116 - __main__ - INFO >>> Energy Consumption Query >>> [Timestamp: 1659180963.68 | Energy Consumption: 19.318549297684513 As]
2022-07-30 13:36:06,116 - __main__ - INFO >>> Container CPU Usage (Percentage) relative to the complete node: 18.25260250000004 %
2022-07-30 13:36:06,116 - __main__ - INFO >>> Energy Consumption of analyze-sentence: 22.164084984030715 As
```

I query the Prometheus REST API every 60 seconds. I`m only getting weird results occasionally, most of the times they make sense. But I can't explain why it is happening at all, no matter at what time i query the Prometheus API, the average CPU Usage of the system should always be higher than the average CPU Usage of a Pod, right?
Do you have any idea where the issue is? Wrong data? Wrong queries? Something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

One way to explain this could be that Prometheus gets your nodes metrics from the node-exporter, and your container metrics from cadvisor.

There's no guarantee Prometheus would scrape metrics from both services at the same time. Prometheus will try proceed with each job at least once every scrape_interval.

Each target would have its metrics collected at some point, but not necessarily the exact same second. Comparing values from different sources, glitches like this could happend.

Comment: Can this really be the case? See the `timestamp`s returned by my API Queries, they seem to be roughly the same. Or are those not the timestamps, at which the data was collected, but only the timestamp it was retrieved from the database? I'm new to Prometheus, so I really can't tell exactly what these timestamps indicate. But yeah, I also think something like that could be the reason...

Comment: The output you shared shows incremental timestamps, almost as if you're querying for `timestamp()`. One way to check for last collection time of your metric would be to use `timestamp(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total)`, and compare it with `timestamp(node_cpu_seconds_total)`. Or `timestamp(powerexporter_power_consumption_ampere_seconds_total)`. Is this what you've been using in the output you shared?

Comment: The timestamps actually arent obtained from own API Calls, the Prometheus REST API actually provides them in combination with the results used in the sample output. I also investigated the graph of the metrics using the Prometheus UI and actually the cpu usage graph of the system seems to be valid, but some parts of the graph corresponding to the pod cpu usage is too high. For example: I limited the usage of the pod to 4 CPU cores, but the PromQL query shows a max value of nearly 5 cores.. I know its not expected to be always <= 4, but I doubt almost 5 is correct.

Comment: Interestingly, if i increase the time interval of the pod cpu usage query from `1m` to like `2m` I get results from that query that make more sense to me.. And yeah, the `timestamp` returns different values for my individual metrics.

Comment: After some more investigation it seems like when the function is not invoked anymore, the CPU usages  of Pod and System decrease to their idle values and the API Call of the system cpu usage returns the actual idle value, but the API Call of the container usage still returns a high number..probably because the API Call happens before the next scrape or something. I guess there is not much I can do about that but to accept that I will sometimes obtain incorrect results.